# Can I use JMX to monitor ColdFusion 10 standard?

Tags: coldfusion, jmx

How do you use JMX to monitor CF10 Standard?

I found this post here but it was written for jvm 1.6 (CF8 days?)
http://boncode.blogspot.com/2010/04/cf-java-using-free-visualvm-tool-to.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, works just fine -- same JVM options are applicable to CF 10.

As a side note, CF 10 still actually uses a 1.6 JVM by default, but one of the patches to CF10 gave it 1.7 compatibility.